# Cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL through Google App Engine with Pdo_Mysql in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, zend-framework2, google-cloud-sql

I have been trying to solve this issue already for a few days without any results. When using default php pdo object I can connect to the database:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project-id:database-instance;dbname=test',
          'root',  // username
          ''       // password
        );
```

But when trying to connect with ZF2 adapter the connection just times out.

```
'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
        'database' => 'test',
        'username' => 'root', 
        'unix_socket' => '/cloudsql/project-id:database-instance',
),
```

I am quite sure that the problem is somehow with the unix_socket as I can connect to the Cloud SQL server from my localhost directly without socket:

```
'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
        'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'database' => 'test',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',

),
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I think this `'/cloudsql/project-id:database-instance'` part should come in the host field, though I work with a different database driver.

Comment: I doubt it, and I also tried, but error occurs: Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed

Comment: Are you trying to connect your App engine instance from your local development environment?

Comment: Nope, only after deploying to the App Engine. I have separate db configs for local and production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unix_socket` isn't a recognized option for the pdo driver (https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php#L164). Try this instead

```
'db' => array(
        'dsn' => 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project-id:database-instance;dbname=test',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',    
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mars, that indeed was the issue, you saved me. I incorrectly read that unix_socket was an option, but it was for different driver.